# Overflow element without cutting absolutely positioned elements in it

Tags: css

In a `container` element I have floated element and an absolutely positioned image that needs to protrude from `container`. However I need `container` to keep its height because it has a `margin-bottom` that separate it from the next block below it.

Problem: `container`'s `overflow: hidden` cuts the image off so it cannot protrude from it. So I have to choose between 2 things I absolutely need: the image to protrude and `container` to keep its height.

How to solve this dilemma?

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='col1'>
        content
    </div>
    <div class='col2'>
        <img src='whatever.jpg'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.col1,
.col2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.col2 {
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the overflow to contain the floats? If so there are several other methods.

These can be found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

The modern method is:

```
.container:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: pink;
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.col1,
.col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
}
.col2 {
  position: relative;
  background: #c0ffee;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='col1'>
    content
  </div>
  <div class='col2'>
    <img src='http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200' />
  </div>
</div>
```